# Transfering data from View form to Model method

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I am building a tic-tac-toe game on RoR. At the moment, the whole board is set up, with a form below it that tracks the moves. I have been told to use the model to figure out such things as if there is a winner(3 in a row), a tie(full board), etc. I thought I had it, but apparently not. Not sure what I'm doing wrong with the `players` method in the model.

`show.html.erb`:

```
<div id="board" align = center>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td data-position="0" class="square <%= class_for_move(0)%>"></td>
      <td data-position="1" class="square v <%= class_for_move(1)%>"></td>
      <td data-position="2" class="square <%= class_for_move(2)%>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-position="3" class="square h <%= class_for_move(3)%>"></td>
      <td data-position="4" class="square v h <%= class_for_move(4)%>"></td>
      <td data-position="5" class="square h <%= class_for_move(5)%>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-position="6" class="square <%= class_for_move(6)%>"></td>
      <td data-position="7" class="square v <%= class_for_move(7)%>"></td>
      <td data-position="8" class="square <%= class_for_move(8)%>"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td><%= @game.player_1 %></td>
    <td><%= @game.player_2 %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>O</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<%= link_to "Play Again", games_path %>

<%= nested_form_for @game do |f| %>

  <%= f.fields_for :moves do |move_form| %>
    <div id="table" data-current-player="<%=session[:current_player] %>">
      <%= move_form.label :position %><br>
      <%= move_form.text_field :player, data: {position: move_form.object.position} %>
      <%= move_form.hidden_field :id %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<input type="Submit">
<% end %>
```

`game.rb`:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :moves
  after_create :initialize_moves
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :moves

  def initialize_moves
    9.times do |i|
      Move.create(position: i, game:self)
    end
  end

  def players(number)
    move = moves.find_by(position: number)
    player = move.player
  end

  def tie?
  end

  def winner?
     if players(0) == players(1) && players(1) == players(2)
      return players(0)
    end
  end

end
```

`games_controller`:

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @game = Game.new(game_params)
    @game.save
    redirect_to @game
  end

  def update
    @game = Game.find(params[:id])
    @game.update(game_params)
    if @game.tie?
      flash[:error] = "Game over. 'Tis a tie."
    elsif @game.winner?
      flash[:notice] = "Winner is #{session[:current_player]}"
    else
      switch_player
    end
    redirect_to @game
  end

  def show
    @game = Game.find(params[:id])
  end

  def switch_player
    session[:current_player] = session[:current_player] == "X" ? "O" : "X"
  end

  private
  def game_params
    params.require(:game).permit(:player_1, :player_2, moves_attributes: [:player, :id])
  end

end
```

When I run what I have at the moment, the game plays out until I have a three-in-a-row(only doing slots 0,1,2 as test at the moment), switching players and acting normal. The moment the three-in-a-row is true, it stays on whatever the current player is, and won't switch. It's not ending the game, or giving me the flash notice. Just sticks to the current player. Same goes with if I try to add an elsif trying to put in another winning position combo.

I realize this is probably elementary level stuff, but I just cannot seem to wrap my head around it, and haven't found anything useful online so far. And, if the `if` statement route isn't the right way to go, I am willing to go another way. I just can't think of a different way at the moment.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I set up a new question with different information so as to not be flooding the site with mostly identical questions.

Comment: Kinda figured... Looks like you're making progress, though. Good luck, it gets way less confusing with time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Just needed to set up each combo in the `winner?` method with `!players(0).blank? &&`. With the respective number for each `players` after `==`.

Was going to delete the question, but just in case anyone was actually curious of the answer, there it is.

Comment: Yeah, don't delete it, maybe someone comes here with a similar problem.